# Why is my SPA, which is calling my WebAPI, using Azure Active Directory, receiving "Authorization has been denied for this request."?

Tags: azure, asp.net-web-api, azure-active-directory, single-page-application, access-token

I have a local SPA client (based on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/tutorial-v2-javascript-spa)

Then there is a WebAPI service. (based on https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-native-desktop)

The service should only respond to authenticated and authorized clients. To this end I am using Azure active directory (AD).

Here a picture of how the 3 parts are linked. Numbers refer to the order of the calls.

[image]

Although Azure AD seems to return an access token to the client, and the client sends the access token to the service in the header, the service responds with

```
Authorization has been denied for this request
```

**Question**
Why does this happen? My gut feeling is that my locally running service is somehow „not talking to Azure AD“.

**Details**

Both the client and the service are „app registrations“ in Azure AD.

[image]

The service exposes an API.

[image]

The service configuration has the „tenant“ and the „audience“. Seems like too little configuration.

[image]

The client has API permissions.

[image]

The client configuration has the client app registration ID.

[image]

The client essentially consists of a button to sign in and a button to get a list of todos from an API. Below a screenshot of the client, and the Firefox developer tools with the login page.

[image]

When the client starts, I first need to authenticate with Azure AD. The client receives the access token. Below the response.

[image]

When I press „Get Todos“ the service is called with the access token but the response is 401.

[image]

The code for getting the todo list

```
function getTodos() {

    myMSALObj.acquireTokenPopup(requestObj).then(function (tokenResponse) {

        var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                console.log("success");                 
            } else {
                console.log("failure");
            }
        }
        const apiUrl = "https://localhost:44321/api/todolist";
        xmlHttp.open("GET", apiUrl, true); // true for asynchronous

        //No, the API sends back this header (to indicate that cross origin requests are allowed). xmlHttp.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'Bearer ' + tokenResponse.accessToken);

        xmlHttp.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + tokenResponse.accessToken);
        xmlHttp.send();

    }).catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
    });

}
```

Comment: Could you please [decode you token here](https://jwt.io/) and see does it contains your required permission.

Comment: Thank you. It's the wrong token. The "aud" field does not point  to the service "https://XXXXXXX/TodoListService-NativeDotNet" but to "https://graph.microsoft.com".

Comment: Is the issue resolved?

Comment: Nope, but it looks like I'm getting a token for the wrong resource. So I'll investigate that and ask a new question if I get stuck ... Your tip certainly helped!

Comment: Access the correct token first. Your code seems okay up to now. Let's see

Comment: Is it working now?