# Why does MSAL loginPopup respond with „the application client asked for scope that doesn't exist on the resource“?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, single-page-application, access-token, azure-ad-msal

(Continuation of question: [Why is my SPA, which is calling my WebAPI, using Azure Active Directory, receiving "Authorization has been denied for this request."?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56937160/why-is-my-spa-which-is-calling-my-webapi-using-azure-active-directory-receivi))

My client SPA is trying to call a protected WebAPI (service). The client uses MSAL (Micosoft Authentication Libraries). The problem happens before calling the API, i.e. in the picture below somewhere between 1 and 2.

[image]

Here is the client

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Quickstart for MSAL JS</title>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bluebird/3.3.4/bluebird.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://secure.aadcdn.microsoftonline-p.com/lib/1.0.2/js/msal.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div>
            <button id="GetTodos" onclick="getTodos()">Get Todos</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script>

        var msalConfig = {
            auth: {
                clientId: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx2427', 
                authority: "https://login.microsoftonline.com/my.tenant"
            },
            cache: {
                cacheLocation: "sessionStorage",
                storeAuthStateInCookie: true
            }
        };


        var requestObj = {
            // scopes: ["user.read"]
            scopes: ["access_as_user"]
        };

        var myMSALObj = new Msal.UserAgentApplication(msalConfig);

        myMSALObj.handleRedirectCallback(authRedirectCallBack);

        function getTodos() {
            console.log("getTodos ...");

            myMSALObj.loginPopup(requestObj)
                .then(response => {
                    myMSALObj.acquireTokenPopup(requestObj).then(function (tokenResponse) {

                        var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                        xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
                            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                                console.log("success");
                                //this.responseText
                            } else {
                                console.log("failure");
                            }
                        }
                        const apiUrl = "https://localhost:44321/api/todolist";
                        xmlHttp.open("GET", apiUrl, true); // true for asynchronous
                        xmlHttp.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + tokenResponse.accessToken);
                        xmlHttp.send();

                    }).catch(function (error) {
                        console.log(error);
                    });
                })
                .catch(err => {
                    // handle error
                    console.log("login popup failed.", err);
                });
        }


        function authRedirectCallBack(error, response) {
            console.log('authRedirectCallBack');
            if (error) {
                console.log(error);
            } else {
                if (response.tokenType === "access_token") {
                    console.log("response.tokenType === access_token");
                } else {
                    console.log("token type is:" + response.tokenType);
                }
            }
        }

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Both client and service are registered apps on Azure Active Directory

[image]

The client has API permissions to access the service.

[image]

And the service does expose an API with the scope access_as_user

[image]

However the call

```
myMSALObj.loginPopup(requestObj)
```

causes

```
ServerError: "AADSTS650053: The application 'ClientSPA' asked for scope 'access_as_user' that doesn't exist on the resource '00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000'.
```

And when using Chrome I get this message

[image]

**Further Investigation**

Instead of asking for scope „access_as_user“, I ask for „user.read“
This gives me an access token. But this causes the WebAPI to respond with

```
Authorization has been denied for this request
```

And when I decode the access token I see that the audience is https://graph.microsoft.com. But I am expecting the audience to be „https://my.tenant/TodoListService-NativeDotNet“. See picture below (the obfuscated lines do contain information that is specific to my user and my registered app)

[image]

**Questions**

1. Where does the resource '00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000' ID come from (it is mentioned in the error message)? It is not the application ID of the client nor of the service.
2. What have I done incorrectly, either in the configuration on Azure Active Directory or in the client?
3. Could CORS be a problem? I have setup the service to allow CORS.

Comment: '00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000' is application Id of  https://graph.microsoft.com. You can refer https://www.shawntabrizi.com/aad/common-microsoft-resources-azure-active-directory/

Comment: So why has my app a reference to graph.microsoft.com? The authentication should go to "https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenant" ?

Comment: Because you did not specify a resource identifier, AAD is attempting to find your scope on Microsoft Graph

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The scope should include the exposing resource's identifier (the Application ID URI). You can find the full value by going to "Expose an API" -> Edit a Scope -> Copy the label at the top...

```
var requestObj = {
    // scopes: ["https://graph.microsoft.com/user.read"]
    scopes: ["https://ServiceWebAPI/TodoListService-NativeDotNet-access_as_user"]
};
```

Further reading on individual scopes here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-permissions-and-consent#requesting-individual-user-consent